# MarketStack API Only Returns IEXG Exchange Data

Tags: api, get, stock

I'm using the Marketstack API and I want to return intradata data for symbols on the Nasdaq. The Nasdaq has a MIC of XNAS. The API documentation for Marketstack uses XNAS in (some of) their examples. However, even if I copy-paste their https formatting directly, I only ever receive data from the IEXG exchange.

I've tried two ways:

```
stock_url = ("https://api.marketstack.com/v1/intraday" + 
             "?access_key=" + API_KEY + 
             "&symbols=" + symbol + 
             "&interval=15min" +
             "&exchange=XNAS" + 
             "&limit=1000" + 
             "&sort=desc")
```

and

```
stock_url = ("https://api.marketstack.com/v1/exchanges/XNAS/intraday" + 
             "?access_key=" + API_KEY + 
             "&symbols=" + symbol + 
             "&interval=15min" +
             "&limit=1000" + 
             "&sort=desc")
```

I've also tried putting the `&exchange` line in the second version as well.

I fetch the data using:

`json.loads(requests.get(stock_url).content)`

Does anyone know why I only ever receive IEXG data? You can see it in the snippet of result below:

```
{'open': 2.05, 'high': 2.06, 'low': 1.94, ... 'symbol': 'EDU', 'exchange': 'IEXG'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same question and I asked MarketStack support. They told me that intraday endpoint supports only one exchange (IEXG). In my opinion, it's not obvious from the common description on their website. The exact answer from support is:

> Currently, Intraday data is available for all US stock tickers with data intervals as short as 1 minute. We are working on expanding our intraday data to other exchanges, at the moment we are using IEX data (Investors Exchange).

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that marketstack currently only returns intraday data from the IEX exchange. I have the "Basic Subscription" plan. I created an application that I hoped would be able to return intraday quotes for 93 symbols. Unfortunately marketstack only returned 78 results... those that were filtered out were not on IEX.

This was troubling since their documentation clearly states you can pick the exchange you want to request data from.

"exchange - [Optional] Filter your results based on a specific stock exchange by specifying the MIC identification of a stock exchange. Example: IEXG"

Unfortunately not all symbols are on IEX, therefore you can't get intraday prices for some pretty standard/popular stock symbols.

A point of confusion for myself, and likely other folks, is that the other endpoints (like "end of day data") provided by marketstack do seem to support the "exchange" query parameter and you can get "end of day" data from any of the exchanges they claim to support. It seems to only be the intraday endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, esp the point about the intraday endpoint vs other endpoints